# FFmpeg Video Merging Length Issue

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have created 2 file 1)first.mp4 and 2) test.mp3 when i am merging this file and created one new video .video is created perfectly done but getting one problem (Audio Problem)

Two file description
first.mp4 in video Length -30Sec
test.mp4 in audio Length -10Sec

How to handle remaining new video in 10Sec after audio not listen problem any way to handle this type of problem or Any way to detect if remaining 20Sec audio set as first.mp4 video length 20Sec to 30Sec audio length set

I am executing below command

```
String videoWithAudio[] = { "ffmpeg", "-i", "/sdcard/first.mp4", "-i",
                    "/sdcard/test.mp3", "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "aac",
                    "-strict", "experimental", "-map", "0:v:0", "-map",
                    "1:a:0", "/sdcard/jointAb.mp4" };
```